# Why does vim ignore commentstring when folding (foldmethod=marker)

Tags: folding, comments

I am editing a HTML document (filetype=html) in vim. `foldmarker` is set to `{,}`, `foldmethod` to `marker` and `commentstring` to `<!--%s-->`.

When I visually select a region and use `zf` to create a folding, vim inserts a `{` at the beginning and a `}` at the end of the region.
However, with my settings, I expected vim to insert `<!--{-->` and `<!--}-->`, respectively.

Why is vim ignoring `commentstring` when folding?

Comment: It works for XML, but doesn't work for HTML, indeed. But if you `setlocal comments=` then it will work.

Comment: cannot reproduce. Please try to come up with a minimal example starting with `vim --clean`

Comment: Sh, it seems to be caused by the `n:>` flag of the 'comments'  option, however, that is not included in the html filetype (so it happens, if you manually override it afterwards). Please check where you set this

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I can reproduce it with `comments=s:<!--,m:    ,e:-->` which is set by html filetype.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt and it happens when you try to do it on a paragraph for example, but don't start and end on empty lines. Just do `zfip`.

Comment: @MaximKim that does not happen for me. A testfile would be good, with exact reproduction steps.

Comment: BTW: In what version does that happen? #1549 could be responsible, but as said before I do not see this.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt you will be surprised... I try to `zfip` on a `lorem ipsum` paragraph and it doesnt work. On a blabla paragraph it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer probably should be deleted. Answering here to show it @ChristianBrabandt.

It is kind of strange but for some text it works, for the other it doesn't:

[image]

And if you change the first paragraph to:

```
blablabla a
lkjsdlfkj
lksjdflksdj
lksjdflksja
```

Then it will not work for the first row. Looks like if there are more than 1 word on the line it doesn't insert commentstring.

vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec  5 2018 23:02:23)
MS-Windows 64-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-565
Compiled by appveyor@APPVYR-WIN
Huge version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl                +comments           +file_in_path       +listcmds           +persistent_undo    +tag_binary         +visualextra
+arabic             +conceal            +find_in_path       +localmap           -postscript         +tag_old_static     +viminfo
+autocmd            +cryptv             +float              +lua/dyn            +printer            -tag_any_white      +vreplace
+autochdir          +cscope             +folding            +menu               +profile            +tcl/dyn            -vtp
+autoservername     +cursorbind         -footer             +mksession          +python/dyn         -termguicolors      +wildignore
+balloon_eval       +cursorshape        +gettext/dyn        +modify_fname       +python3/dyn        +terminal           +wildmenu
-balloon_eval_term  +dialog_con_gui     -hangul_input       +mouse              +quickfix           -tgetent            +windows
+browse             +diff               +iconv/dyn          +mouseshape         +reltime            -termresponse       +writebackup
++builtin_terms     +digraphs           +insert_expand      +multi_byte_ime/dyn +rightleft          +textobjects        -xfontset
+byte_offset        +directx            +job                +multi_lang         +ruby/dyn           +timers             -xim
+channel            -dnd                +jumplist           +mzscheme/dyn       +scrollbind         +title              +xpm_w32
+cindent            -ebcdic             +keymap             +netbeans_intg      +signs              +toolbar            -xterm_save
+clientserver       +emacs_tags         +lambda             +num64              +smartindent        +user_commands      
+clipboard          +eval               +langmap            +ole                +startuptime        +vartabs            
+cmdline_compl      +ex_extra           +libcall            +packages           +statusline         +vertsplit          
+cmdline_hist       +extra_search       +linebreak          +path_extra         -sun_workshop       +virtualedit        
+cmdline_info       +farsi              +lispindent         +perl/dyn           +syntax             +visual             
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\vimrc"
 3rd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$HOME\vimfiles\gvimrc"
3rd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME\defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32  -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_TERMINAL -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG -DFEAT_JOB_CHANNEL   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MP -DHAVE_STDINT_H /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_MBYTE -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DFEAT_DIRECTX -DDYNAMIC_DIRECTX -DFEAT_DIRECTX_COLOR_EMOJI -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl86t.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.6\" -DFEAT_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA -DDYNAMIC_LUA_DLL=\"lua53.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python37.dll\" -DFEAT_MZSCHEME -I "C:\Program Files\Racket\include" -DMZ_PRECISE_GC -DDYNAMIC_MZSCHEME -DDYNAMIC_MZSCH_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_MZGC_DLL=\"libracket3m_a36fs8.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl528.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=24 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"x64-msvcrt-ruby240.dll\" -DFEAT_HUGE /Fd.\ObjGXOULYHTRZAMD64/ /Zi
Linking: link  /nologo /subsystem:windows,5.02 /opt:ref /LTCG:STATUS /HIGHENTROPYVA:NO oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib netapi32.lib uuid.lib /machine:AMD64 gdi32.lib version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib netapi32.lib  /machine:AMD64  libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib user32.lib  /nodefaultlib:lua53.lib  /STACK:8388608  /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python37.lib   "C:\Tcl\lib\tclstub86.lib" WSock32.lib xpm\x64\lib-vc14\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me and seems to be caused by v8.0.0453 if my short testing was correct. Can someone create an issue for that?

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3670
@ChristianBrabandt could you step in and comment there about vim version caused the issue?

Comment: should be fixed now

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, yes I have checked it with the new build -- it is fixed.